# Typescript keyof in dictionary mandatoriness

Tags: typescript

Why do I have different results from these seemingly same definitions?

```
type a = {va?: string}
let t1: {[id in keyof a]: number} = {} // ok, va is optional
type keyOfa = keyof a
let t2: {[id in keyOfa]: number} = {}  // error, va is mandatory

type b = {vb?: string}
let t3: {[id in keyof (a & b)]: number} = {}     // ok, va and vb are optional
let t4: {[id in keyof a | keyof b]: number} = {} // error, va and vb are mandatory
let t5: {[id in keyOfa | keyof b]: number} = {}  // error, va and vb are mandatory
```

In the examples above, `t1` and `t3` retain the mandatoriness (i.e. keeping both `va` and `vb` optional).

However, `t2`, `t4` and `t5` turn all the properties into mandatory.

Is this a bug in Typescript?

Comment: Using keyof in mapped types retains information about that key. For example, the key retains whether or not it's optional or readonly.

Comment: @catgirlkelly yeah, and my question is showing that is not always the case

Comment: @ShubhamWaje but keyof in `t1` and `t3` retains the optional-ness, why?

Answer (score 0):

The keyof operator takes an object **type** and produces a **string** or **numeric literal** union of its keys.

From my extremely smooth brain I think this could mean that the nullable detail is lost when this happens.

Comment: that would be good if it was consistent and it is not